# Store mounts in a variable and comment or disable swap mount

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

**Newbie alert!!**

The idea is to **list the mounts in fstab that contains the word swap and store them in a variable** then disable or commenting it.
I can easily disable it by using regex as:

```
- name: Force quit swap
  command: swapoff {{ swap.stdout }}

- name: Disabling swap
  shell: "swapoff --all"
  become: true

- name: Disable swap permanently, persist reboots
  replace:
    path: /etc/fstab
    regexp: '^([^#].*?\sswap\s+sw\s+.*)$'
    replace: '# \1'
    backup: yes
```

But I was asked to use **ansible_mount** instead.
can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [mount](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html) documentation and use status `absent`.

```
- name: Unmount swap
  mount:
    name: swap
    fstype: swap
    state: absent
```